# jQuery change images on links hover

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-hover, jquery-attributes

I have a problem with a code below. Somehow I'm not able to change image background using jQuery script.

HTML code looks like:

- part to display an image:

  ```
  <div class="group-image img-responsive img-ctr"></div>
  ```
- part to generate related links (simplified):

  `<a class="hoverlink" href="{complete_path}" data-img="{cat_image_path}">{cat_name}</a>`

jQuery code looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.hoverlink').hover(function(){$('.group-image').css('background', $(this).attr('data-img'))});
});
```

data-image tag contains correct URL to an image for related links, but when I hover any of those links it doesn't add `background` CSS to `group-image` div. [JSFillde](http://jsfiddle.net/hLyw72Lx/2/) of an examle

Any clue where I have made an error?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.hoverlink').hover(function(){
    $('.group-image').css('background-image', 'url('+$(this).attr('data-img')+')')
});
```

This works!!
Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hLyw72Lx/6/)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `url('')` from your background assignment: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hLyw72Lx/7/)**

```
$('.hoverlink').hover(function(){
    $('.group-image').css('background', "url('" + $(this).attr('data-img') + "')")
});
```